# *Language name* is awesome!

Tags: code-golf

Write a program in any language that reads input from stdin and outputs a slightly modified output to stdout. The program should borrow some characters from the input and output as large of a prefix as possible of `*language-name* is awesome!` followed by a newline and then what's left of the input.

- The input does not contain any uppercase characters.
- If the first character of the language name is not present in the string, only the newline character should be borrowed.
- If there's no newline character in the input, output the input unmodified.
- It does not matter which of the available characters you borrow.

I'm using `\n`as the newline character (`0x0a`) to save space when writing. The real program should only care about the real newline character, not the `\n` string.

Example: python.
input: `abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz\n0123456789`
output: `python\nabcdefgijklmqrsuvwxz0123456789`
Since the input does not have any spaces, we cannot continue even though we have enough characters for the next word: `is`.

Example: C.
input: `i don't see anything!`
output: `i don't see anything!`
C was not found in the string, so no modification was possible. Also, no newline character is present.

Example: C++.
input: `i don't\nsee anything!`
output: `\ni don'tsee anything!`
C was not found in the string, so no modification was possible.

Example: Obj-C.
input: `objectively, clojure is amazing.\nq.e.d.`
output: `obj\nectively, clojure is amazing.q.e.d.`
The input contains enough characters to write `obj` but the `-` is missing.

Byte count of your source code minus the byte count of your languages' name, utf-8 encoded (if possible), is your score; lowest wins!

Comment: Let's hope someone finds a language with a lot of repetition in the name for a negative score :)

Comment: Could you include `i don't\nsee anything!` as a test case?

Comment: Good test case! Added.

Comment: How should cases with repeated characters (either in the name or in the input) be handled? Does the order of the left-over characters in the output matter?

Comment: Woops! Fixed it. Also clarified that any character may be borrowed, not just the first.

Comment: In the last example, there is a '-' in output. Where does it come from?

Comment: And, in the last example, where does the 'a' come from, as it's still present 2 times in 'amazing'? Maybe you should check the examples again?

Comment: Needless to say, I did not write a solution to this problem myself. I did the examples by hand. Corrected the last one now.

Comment: Could you please add a test-case that uses `is awesome`, and one that contains the necessary letters but *not* a newline?

Answer (score 4):

## Pyth, 37 bytes

```
.-Jjb.zpef!.-TJ+,kb+Rb._"pyth is awesome!
```

The source code is **41 bytes** long. [Try it online.](https://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=.-Jjb.zpef%21.-TJ%2B%2Ckb%2BRb._"pyth+is+awesome%21&input=abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz%0A0+1+2+3+4+5+6+7+8+9)

#### How it works

```
  Jjb.z                                      Save all user input in J.
                      ._"pyth is awesome!    Compute all prefixes that string:
                                               ["p", "py", ... ]
                   +Rb                       Append a linefeed to each prefix.
               +,kb                          Concatenate ["", "\n"] with the result.
         f                                   Filter the resulting array; for each T:
           .-TJ                                Perform bagwise difference between T
                                               and J (respects multiplicities).
         !                                     Take the logical NOT.
                                             Keep T if ! returned True, i.e., if J
                                             contains all of T's characters.
        e                                    Retrieve the last, longest match.
       p                                     Print it.
.-J                                          Remove its characters from J.
                                             (implicit) Print the result.
```

Answer (score 2):

### Python, 186 - 6 = 180

```python
import sys
a=sys.stdin.read()
s="python is awesome!"
r=''
if'\n'not in a:print a;exit()
a=a.replace('\n','',1)
for c in s:
 if c in a:a,r=a.replace(c,'',1),r+c
 else:break
print r+'\n'+a
```

[Try it online](http://ideone.com/XL5yI8)

Comment: It should only borrow characters, so if multiple newlines are present in the input, you only borrow one of them. All the characters should still be there in the output, but not necessarily in the same order.

Answer (score 1):

### Python, 146 bytes

```
import sys
r=sys.stdin.read();y='\npython is awesome!';a=''
for i in y:
    if i in r:a+=i
    else:break
print a[1:]+'\n'+''.join(b for b in r if not b in a)
```

Comment: @Dennis fixed it -_-

Comment: Still one newline too many if the input doesn't contain newlines (second example).

Answer (score 1):

## Ceylon, 235 - 6 = 229

`void a(){variable value i="";variable value r="\nceylon is awesome!";while(exists l=process.readLine()){i=i+"\n"+l;}i=i.rest;for(j->c in r.indexed){if(c in i){i=i.replaceLast(c.string,"");}else{r=r[0:j];break;}}print(r.rest+r[0:1]+i);}`

Here is a formatted and commented version:

```
void a() {
    // our target string, with the \n shuffled to the start.
    variable value r = "\nceylon is awesome!";

    // read the whole input line by line
    // (there doesn't seem a way to do this shorter :-/)
    variable value i = "";
    while (exists l = process.readLine()) {
        i = i + "\n" + l;
    }
    // remove first \n:
    i = i.rest;
    for (j->c in r.indexed) {
        if (c in i) {
            // remove some occurence of c
            i = i.replaceLast(c.string, "");
        } else {
            // stop the loop, and take the part of `r` processed so far.
            r = r[0:j];
            break;
        }
    }
    // reshuffle first \n in r to its end.
    // This will result in the empty string if r is empty, i.e. no \n was found.
    print(r.rest + r[0:1] + i);
}
```

It uses `replaceLast` instead of `replaceFirst` because it is shorter.

Some example inputs and outputs in the same format as in the question:

- `abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz\n0123456789` → `ceylon\nabdfghijkmpqrstuvwxz0123456789`
- `i don't see anything!` → `i don't see anything!`
- `i don't\nsee anything!` → `\ni don't see anything!`
- `objectively, closure is amazing.\nq.e.d.` → `ceylon is a\nobjectivel, sureiamzng.\q..d.`

Answer (score 1):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 23 - 5 = 18 bytes

```
“£İþ¬Ɠ¥ỊḊ»
¢œ-ƤṆ€×¢Ṅœ-@
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##AW0Akv9qZWxsef//4oCcwqPEsMO@wqzGk8Kl4buK4biKwrsKwqLFky3GpOG5huKCrMOXwqLhuYTFky1A/8OH//9hYmNkZWZnaGlqa2xtbm9wcXJzdHV2d3h5egowMTIzNDU2Nzg5Cmx5IGlzIGF3ZSst)

This uses the [Jelly encoding](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jellylanguage/wiki/Code-page). Insisting on UTf-8 encoding has the same byte count, it just means I need to make a hexdump of the bytes.

### How it works

```
“£İþ¬Ɠ¥ỊḊ» - Helper link. Compressed string "jelly is awesome"

¢œ-ƤṆ€×¢Ṅœ-@ - Main link. Takes S on the left
¢            - Yield "jelly is awesome"
   Ƥ         - Over each prefix of "jelly is awesome":
 œ-          -   For each character in the prefix, remove it exactly once
                  if it is in the input
                  This results in an empty list if the entire prefix is in
                  the input else a non-empty list
     €       - Over each:
    Ṇ        -   Logical NOT. This yields 1 for an empty list, else 0
       ¢     - Yield "jelly is awesome"
      ×      - For each character, keep it if the left argument is 1
        Ṅ    - Print the kept characters with a trailing newline
         œ-@ - Remove exactly one occurrence of each of the kept characters
               from the input and output that
```

Answer (score 0):

## JavaScript (ES6) 90 (100-10)

As a function returning the requested ouput. It's difficult to implement with I/O, as the usual substitute for STDIN is `prompt()`, that does not accept a newline inside the input string.

As a function with real output (using `alert`) the byte count is 107

```
f=s=>alert(([...`
javascript is awesome`].every(c=>(z=s.replace(c,''))!=s&&(s=z,q?o+=c:q=c),q=o=''),o+q+z))
```

Test running the snippet below in an EcmaScript 6 compliant browser (implementing spread operator and arrow function - I use FireFox)

```js
f=s=>([...`
javascript is awesome`].every(c=>(z=s.replace(c,''))!=s&&(s=z,q?o+=c:q=c),q=o=''),o+q+z)

function test()
{
  O.innerHTML=f(I.value)
}

test()
```

```css
#I {width: 80%}
```

```html
<textarea id=I>
objectively, clojure is amazing.
q.e.d.</textarea><button onclick="test()">-></button>
<pre id=O></pre>
```

Answer (score 0):

## JavaScript (ES7), <s>101</s> 107 - 10 = 97

It was shorter before, and even worked on all four test cases, but apparently I missed a rule, so....

```js
x=>(i=r=q='',[for(c of`
javascript is awesome`)(y=x.replace(c,''),i||y==x?i=1:(c<' '?q=c:r+=c,x=y))],r+q+x)
```

Works properly in Firefox 42. This originally started out at 119 bytes, but a trick from [@edc65's answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/61757/42545) helped to shorten it a great deal. I think there's still some room for improvement. As always, suggestions welcome!

Comment: Fails when missing newline in input. Test `obj` -> `job`, should be not modified (rule 3)

Comment: @edc65 Ah, yes, the test cases only cover 75% of the edge cases. I could even remove `is awesome` and it would still work properly on all four of them. I'll fix this ASAP.

Answer (score 0):

## Perl, 72 - 4 = 68 bytes

Includes 2 switches.

```
perl -0pe 'for$c("\nperl is awesome!"=~/./gs){s/$c//?$p.=$c:last}s/^/$p\n/;s/\n//'
```

*Explanation*: For every character in the string `"\nperl is awesome"`, remove the corresponding character from the input string (`$_`) till we find a character not present in `$_`. The matching characters are stored in `$p` which is prefixed to `$_` which is then printed.

The `-0` switch reads in the complete input rather than line-by-line and the `-p` switch makes reading input and print the output implicit.